# Could not extract ResultSet SQL Spring Boot POST not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdaI4.png)

I am getting the following 500 error on a POST not sure what is wrong, I have tried cleaning up the entity class

**Error**
{timestamp: 1654227336348, status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error",…}
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
path: "/api/marathon/baselineTools/resourceAssignments"
status: 500
timestamp: 1654227336348

```
@RequestMapping(value = "resourceAssignments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() && (hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') || hasRole('ROLE_BASELINETOOLS'))")
    public List<ResourceAssignments> getResourceAssignments(@RequestBody BaselineData data) {
        int reportingProjectId = data.getReportingProjectId();
        String phase = data.getPhase();

        return this.resourceAssignmentsRepository.findAllByReportingProjectIdAndPhase(String.valueOf(reportingProjectId), phase);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error log?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).